Why occurs error excuting `kubectl create -f` with root?
I've been studying Kubernetes for a week to apply it to a side project. But just now, I met a problem which seemed to be an issue with my Ubuntu account.
enter image description here
If I ran kubectl create -f  command with my default account of GCP Web SSH, it works without problem.
enter image description here
However, If I ran same command with root account, it goes crashed and the following error message appears.
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "http-go-pod-v2.yaml": pods "http-go" is forbidden: pod does not have "kubernetes.io/config.mirror" annotation, node "master-1" can only create mirror pods

I found out that there is no problem if I use the default account, but I want to solve this problem from the cause with detail.
Why can't the root account run?

its because your linux root account probably does not have the cluster credentials which your normal username has  ... copy it from your normal linux account into your root account ... not necessarily however typical credential file location is at ${HOME}/.kube/config
